# Delete multiple songs from Apple Music

Tags: apple-music

I accidentally added a playlist to my apple music that has 300+ songs.  I removed the playlist, but the songs are still cluttering up my apple music library.

I can delete them one at a time, but this is tedious.  Is there a way to delete more than one song at at time or wipe out the library completely?

I've tried logging into music.apple.com and selecting multiple songs. But when choosing "Delete from Library" it only deletes one song.

[image: Screenshot of Delete from Library]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to a desktop Apple Music client (for macOS or Microsoft Windows) you can delete multiple tracks at once by selecting them, right-clicking and choosing Delete From Library. This is easier in the macOS client because it has a column browser feature in the Songs view that makes sorting tracks easier. You can use the View menu to turn the feature on and customise the columns.

If you only have access to Microsoft Windows, iTunes also has the column browser feature. I believe iTunes is now deprecated in favour of Apple Music, but it should still be available for download.

It may help to re-add the playlist so that you have all the songs in one place for ease of deletion.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you!